# creating a table in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a table to my DB, but my code isn't working. does someone know what i did wrong?

```
$createSUTable_SQL = "CREATE TABLE site_users(company_ID INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
        company_CNPJ INT( 11 ) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , 
        company_Name VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , 
        name_Responsable  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
        company_Category  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
        company_Street  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
        company_Number  INT( 20 ) NOT NULL , 
        company_Number2  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
        company_Town  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
        company_State  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
        company_Postcode  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
        name_Country  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL )";


    if (mysql_query($createSUTable_SQL)){
        echo "'Create TABLE site_uers' - Successful. <br/><br/>";
    } else {
        echo "'Create TABLE site_uers' - Failed. <br/><br/>";
    }
```

The response works, but for some reason I am unable to create the table.

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: If you've tried it multiple times, is there any chance it's failing because the database already exist?

Comment: odd, because if mysql_query returns true then the query worked (in theory). how are you checking the table exists(or not)?

Comment: You have an incorrect table definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have output `mysql_error()` in your `else` clause if the query failed.

This generates the following error:

```
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

The meaning of this error should be pretty clear. Your `AUTO_INCREMENT` column should also be your `PRIMARY KEY` column.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that `company_ID` isn't defined as PRIMARY key, which is necessary for auto increment.

Making `company_ID` a primary key isn't possible, because you already have a primary key defined. But you can still change `company_CNPJ` to unique, which works

```
CREATE TABLE site_users(company_ID INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    company_CNPJ INT( 11 ) NOT NULL UNIQUE , 
    company_Name VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , 
    name_Responsable  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
    company_Category  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
    company_Street  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
    company_Number  INT( 20 ) NOT NULL , 
    company_Number2  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
    company_Town  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
    company_State  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
    company_Postcode  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , 
    name_Country  VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(company_id))
```

if you want that company_CNPJ is your primary key, you can make company_ID just an id - but in general, auto increment fields are mostly declared as a primary